# how different is Europa from Eclipse-Galileo-MTJ?

Tags: mtj, eclipse-europa

Hi All
I am doing my coding in J2ME (MIDlets)... can you guys tell me which platform should I choose... eclipse Europa or Eclipse-Galileo-MTJ .. which is better and Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the times newer versions are better, especially in stable releases, Galileo is newer.